# Monodroid: Searchable widget doesnt appear

Tags: android, metadata, xamarin.android

I have this code on the top of my class List activity that I want to search something:

```
[Activity (Label = "Customers")]
[IntentFilter (new[]{Intent.ActionSearch}),
    MetaData ("Search", Resource="@XML/searchable")]
```

and mandroid generate everything, but when I want to press the button to search from the Android emulator, it doesnt apeear. Does someone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [IntentFilter (new[]{Intent.ActionSearch}), 
    MetaData ("android.app.searchable", Resource="@xml/searchable")]
```